# Ruby on Rails Iteration of two tables, loading id

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

learning Rails I encountered a problem. I don't know how to encrypt two tables and how to read the service ID.

First problem. I would like to display the average of service / service ratings (rating.rate) along with the service table.

I have 2 tables:

```
class Service < ApplicationRecord
belongs_to :user
has_many :ratings, :foreign_key => “service_id”
end

class Rating < ApplicationRecord
belongs_to :user
belongs_to :service
end
```

and devise:

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
:recoverable, :rememberable, :validatable
has_many :services, :foreign_key => “user_id”
has_many :ratings, :foreign_key => “user_id”
end
```

I would like to enumerate Service and Rating and display them in one table. I created a variable:

```
@services = Service.left_outer_joins(:ratings) (I don't know if this is good, but it doesn't display an error)
```

I iterated the services like this:
`<% @services.each do |service| %>` and it was good.
Unfortunately, I do not know how to spell services with ratings with left outer join (so that where the rating is, it would display the average of all user ratings, and where there is null, it would be "none")

The second problem is when adding a new rating, how to read service_id?
user_id from devise loading in create method:

```
@service.user = current_user
```

Where should the best add button be located to read service_id from there? index or show or something else?

I hope that I described my problems quite clearly and did not mix up anything :)

Comment: first problem solved, it was enough to do it like this:
<% @services.each do |service, rating| %>